# Compared with non class/module error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, typeerror, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to limit the number of albums a user can create by only showing a link to a new album if the number of albums is greater than 3. The error I am getting says 'compared with non class/module'

```
<% if @albums < 3 %>

     <div class="all-albums" id="position-albums">
        <%= link_to 'New Album', "/albums/new", :style => "text-decoration:none; color:black; font-size: 20px;" %>
        <div class="plus-sign">
            <%= link_to '+', "/albums/new", :style => "text-decoration:none; color:black; font-size:80px; color:#85adad;" %>
        </div>
     </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: what is the type of album in your controller?
can you add the respected method in controller?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `@albums` is an AR collection, you can call `size`, `length` or `count` methods to identify the number of objects within it. For instance:

```
<% if @albums.size <= 3 %>
```

Also, you should use `<=` instead of `<`, according to your post.

All of these 3 methods differ from each other and you should pick the one you need depending on your situation:

- calling `count` (without the block) is going to execute a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query. You should use this method in case it's crucial for you to get the latest calculation result from db instead of using a cached version based on the loaded results or in case you don't actually need the records themselves, just the count calculations.
- calling `length` is going to execute a `SELECT *` query and call `size` method on the resulting collection (without producing any further queries to db). It's preferable  in case you are going to use the underlying records anyway.
- calling `size` on the collection that is not loaded yet is going to execute a `SELECT COUNT(*)`. Otherwise `size` method is going to be called on the loaded collection (without producing any further queries to db).